# List Interface and ArrayList Class: ensureCapacity() and trimToSize() methods

Tags: java, list, oop, arraylist

I'm creating two `Arraylist`s, and then I want to apply `ensureCapacity()` and `trimToSize()`, but

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.trimToSize();
arrayList.ensureCapacity(100);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.trimToSize();
list.ensureCapacity(100);
```

when I'm creating `Arraylist` from Class, I can do that.

And when I'm creating `Arraylist` using `List` Interface, I can't.

Can you tell me please why so?

I've looked into Javadoc and I see that only `ArrayList` has `ensureCapacity()` and `trimToSize()` methods.

But why I can't use them on my `ArrayList` when I create it from `List` interface?

Comment: Related (and possible duplicate): [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: @maloomeister You misunderstood the question. `List` doesn't declare methods `trimToSize()` and `ensureCapacity()`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko no, that link was on purpose. I know that `List` doesn't declare those methods. But the linked Q&A has a lot of information which I thought would easily clear up the confusion about "_i see that only ArrayList has ensureCapacity and trimToSize methods, but why i cant use them on my ArrayList when i create it from List interface?_" I understood the question in the way: "_what's the difference between_ `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>()` and `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>()`?".

Comment: @maloomeister The point remains. Provided link doesn't contain information about `trimToSize()` and `ensureCapacity()` and doesn't explain why they are residing on a class level and not accessible via interface.

Comment: @maloomeister *what's the difference between List<String> list = new ArrayList<>() and ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>()* - the question is not framed like that, its only your interpretation. Let's OP say their word.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko again, seems relatively clear. OP clearly already came to the conclusion that "_only ArrayList has ensureCapacity and trimToSize methods_". So this is obviously a given. However, it is not asked about the _why is that_, instead the question is "_why i cant use them on my ArrayList when i create it from List interface?_".  But nevertheless, there is no point going back and forth here now.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko you're not seeing the forest for the trees, in this case. The specific instance of this problem may involve those two methods, but the overall problem is still a misunderstanding of polymorphism and abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods `trimToSize()` and `ensureCapacity()` are available only in the `ArrayList` class.

There's no such methods in the `List` interface.

The reason for that: these methods are meant to change the size of the underlying array. `trimToSize()` creates a new array of length equal to the  size of the list, and `ensureCapacity()` will create a new underlying array of the given length.

These methods don't make sens for the `LinkedList` which isn't backed by an array, therefore they are not declared in the `List` interface.

It's also worth to point out that `trimToSize()` should be used with caution because you can create a cycle or continuous growth and trimming and `ArrayList` would perform very badly.

Consider this: about `50%` of elements were removed from your `ArrayList` and you what to release this unoccupied heap space with `trimToSize()`. A new underlying array twice smaller would be created and all existing elements would be copied into it. But with the next added item `ArrayList` would become two times bigger again (it means a new array should be allocated in memory and all elements should be copied into it). Doesn't sound very performant.

In general, `trimToSize()` is something that might be worth knowing about because it's a part of the JDK, and because someone might ask you about it, for instance, during an interview. But you would never use it.

> But why I can't use them on my `ArrayList` when I create it from `List` interface?

When a variable is of type `List` you can use only methods that are declared in the list interface. The type of reference defines how you can interact with the object. A reference isn't an object itself. And it does not change the object anyhow, your `ArrayList` still remains to be an `ArrayList`. A reference type `List` defines a way to interact with the object (which is still an `ArrayList`).

In order to access its methods that are not defined in the `List` interface, you can cast it:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<String> list2 = (ArrayList) list;
list2.trimToSize();
list2.ensureCapacity(100);
```

But note that this casting is unsafe, it will succeed only if variable `list` points to an `ArrayList` and not `LinkedList`. And as I've said earlier, it's OK to play with these methods, but you would hardly need them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something important you are missing about Java. You say:

> When I'm creating `ArrayList` from the class, I can do that.
>
> And when I'm creating `ArrayList` using the `List` interface, I can't.

This is not correct.  In both cases you are creating an `ArrayList` using `new ArrayList<>()`.  The two objects are being created in exactly the same way.

The difference between the two versions is in what happens **after** the `ArrayList` objects are created.

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

assigns the new object to a variable whose type is `ArrayList<String>`, but

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

assigns the new object to a variable whose type is `List<String>`.

The difference is in the types of the respective *variables* ... not the types of the objects.

- For `arrayList`, the compiler knows that the object that the variable refers to will be an `ArrayList` or a subtype of `ArrayList`.  Therefore it knows that that object will support all of the methods defined by `ArrayList` and/or its superclasses.  That includes `ArrayList.trimToSize()`.
- For `list`, the compiler **only** knows that the object in the variable is *some* class that implements the `List` interface.  So it only knows that it has methods in the `List` API.  The compiler *doesn't* know if the object is actually an `ArrayList`, or a `LinkedList`, or a `CopyOnWriteList` or any other class that implements `List`.  So methods that are NOT in the `List` API cannot be applied to it.

  Hence the compilation errors.

---

> But why I can't use them on my `ArrayList` when I create it from List interface?

<sup>(You didn't ... see above.)</sup>

Because you assign the `ArrayList` object to a `List` variable, you are saying to the compiler:

> *"Forget that this is an `ArrayList`.  Think of it as a `List`."*